# How to write an automated build script using nmake?

Tags: python, python-3.x, build, automation, subprocess

I'm trying to write an automated build script in python

```
p = subprocess.Popen('%comspec% /k "C:/"Program Files (x86)"/"Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0"/VC/vcvarsall.bat" amd64',
                shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True,
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate(input="nmake -f win32/Makefile.msc")
```

There are no problems with the Makefile, but there is no build when the script is run

Comment: I am unfamiliar with namke (I use make) but normally you would like to add it to the path and try and build manually after a couple of time you would get the hang of it automation should come easy.
In other words - did you try running these actions manually

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.